# end index in binary search

Tags: c, arrays, binary-search

I have a couple of questions in binary search.

1. In my code below, I'm passing fun(array, 0, len-1) from main. Is it also okay to pass 'len' as the end index? I think it's okay, have verified answer as well.

I feel the only difference is that there will be one less computation in the part of the array post the mid element, and one extra computation in the part of the array before the mid element.

2. Also, upon doing mid = (s+e)/2, generally integer division takes the floor value. What if we did mid = (ceiling)(s+e)/2. Again, I feel the only difference is that there will be one less computation in the part of the array post the mid element, and one extra computation in the part of the array before the mid element.

My code below

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int key = 0;
int len = 0;

int main(void)
{
 int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

 printf("Enter key : ");
 scanf("%d",&key);

 len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) - 1;

 printf("Array : ",print(a));
 //printf("Element found at index : %d",fun(a,0,len-1));
 printf("Element found at index : %d",fun(a,0,len));

 printf("\n");
 return 0;
}

int fun(int a[], int s, int e)
{
 int mid = 0;
 mid = (s+e)/2;

 if(a[mid] == key)
  return mid;

 if(s == e)
  return -1;

 if(a[mid] > key)
  fun(a,s,mid-1);
 else
  fun(a,mid+1,e);
}
int print(int a[])
{
 int i = 0;
 for(i=0;i<len;i++)
  printf("%d ",a[i]);
 printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with **printf("Array : ",print(a));** ? You need to use a for loop to print all the values in the array. Also, you have statically initialized the array. Why are you calculation the **len** then?

Comment: @abhishek_naik, forgot to copy the print function. See edit above.

Comment: Note that the output from `print()` will appear before any of the output from the function `printf()` that is passed (but does not use) the non-existent return value from `print()`.  This is not going to give you the result you want; the label will appear after, not before, the data.

Comment: What if you tried searching an empty array?

Comment: Also, it's extremely confusing if `len` does not represent the *length of the array*.  Define clear semantics: do you want it to represent the array length, or do you want it to represent the last valid index?

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,passing `len` and `len-1` will make just this change that number of recursion calls, it will differ for elements before mid element and for elements post of mid element.

And same will be true for using `ceil`. So yes number of recursion calls may differ for different elements based on their `index` in array.

And both the changes will give you correct results.

Comment: thanks . But is there a pattern which can be observed for the two cases of passing len and len-1 with regard to the number of computations?  As in, something like passing len wil result in one less computation on the right side of mid, but one extra computation on the left side of mid. I feel no such pattern can be observed because the one extra computation you save on the right side by passing len can be lost if a computation on the left did say (2+3)/2 = 2 as opposed to (2+2)/2 = 2. So it's 2 in both cases.  Please note in my original code len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a); no -1.

Comment: @PepperBoy  See if you want to search `4` in this array then when you pass `len` recursion calls will be `3` as it is in mid , but if you pass `len-1` then number of recursion calls will be `0` .You can easily make you program count for number of calls .That will clear your thoughts on this .

Comment: thanks , yes I understand. One last question would be, what is the best to pass as the end index? len? len-1? something else? ----->( As I said above, please note that in my original code len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a); There is no -1 at the end. So, in your previous post, passing len-2 would give 0 recursive calls, and passing len-1 would give 3 recursive calls. )

Comment: @PepperBoy In your code posted `len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) -1` is present there.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you pass `len` in place of `len-1` it won't change much. If `len` is odd then `len-1` will be even and both will give same `mid` value.
   If `len` is even then you have two elements in mid position. Here `len-1` will give us the first mid point and `len` will give the second one.
2. If you are using `ceil((s+e)/2)` to get `mid` position then in the case of even `len` it won't affect more, it will give the second mid position even if you pass `len` or `len-1`. But in the case of odd `len`, if you are passing `len` as `e` then it will not make even partitions. It is okay if you are passing `len-1`.

Comment: Can someone please explain what's reason behind down voting this answer? I will be upvoting it in a while, after I've got a reply.

Comment: If he had proper reason, he would have had commented before down voting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass both `len` and `len-1` without any changes in the result except that it won't find the value at the last index.

If you change this line `len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) - 1;`

to `len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);`

then both `len` and `len-1` will work fine.

Also you should return your `fun` function to get the value and also check it before printing in the main function.

Comment: `len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);` friend this is wrong. It assigns `len = 9`. And `a[9]` doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right, but you missed one thing, that is that in the recursive calls if the key is in last index(i.e, 8), then the value of `mid` in that recursive call will be 8, then `mid = (s+e)/2` will be (8+9)/2, i.e, 17/2 which is 8 and after that there is `if(s==e) return -1;` statement. Therefore, the condition of mid=9 will never reach. And that's why I mentioned to check the return value in each call and also in main function. The code would work fine for all odd and even lengths.

Comment: Also instead of `sizeof(*a)`, `sizeof(int)` might be better, but its fine here.

Comment: @RahulBhartari `sizeof(*a)` and `sizeof(int)` would be the same in this case, and `sizeof *a` is usually preferable because it's less error-prone.

Comment: @GajendraBagali To be fair, `sizeof a / sizeof *a` is a normal way of computing an array length.  The real problem is that `len` does not represent an array length in the original code.